# UIBarButton not executing Action

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uibarbuttonitem

I am having a problem: I have programatically created a UIBarButton in my UiNavigation controller. However, I want it to, when pressed, bring up an alert. However, when I use a custom bar button with custom text, it doesn't work:

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
UIBarButtonItem *addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Subscribe" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:nil action:@selector(subscribe:)];

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addButton;
```

But when I do a normal bar button, it works fine:

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
UIBarButtonItem *addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAction target:self action:@selector(subscribe:)];

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addButton;
```

Here is the void:

```
-(void)subscribe:(id)sender {

    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Highscore" message:@"" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];

    [alert show];

}
```

Thanks in advance, 
Rafee

Answer (score 2, accepted):

replace the `nil` you pass as `target:` in the init call

```
[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Subscribe" 
                                 style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone 
                                target:nil  <---
                                action:@selector(subscribe:)];
```

with `self`. Your alloc init should look like this:

```
[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Subscribe" 
                                 style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone 
                                target:self
                                action:@selector(subscribe:)];
```

Messages to nil won't have an effect ;-)

Answer (score 0):

`target` must be `self` , not `nil`. Else no-one receives the action!